# Typescript + React Testing Library - 'SidebarItem' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof SidebarItem'?ts(2749)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm creating a test for a simple React component using Jest + RTL.

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';

import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    centeredContent: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    text: {
        paddingLeft: theme.spacing(5),
    },
    spacer: {
        paddingLeft: theme.spacing(5),
    },
}));

interface SidebarItemProps {
    children: any; //TODO - find an extensible type that we can use for {children}
    text?: string;
    openSidebar: boolean;
}

const SidebarItem: React.FC<SidebarItemProps> = ({ children, text, openSidebar }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <ListItem button className={classes.centeredContent}>
            {!openSidebar && <Grid className={classes.spacer} />}
            <ListItemIcon>{children}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText className={classes.text} primary={text} primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'body1' }} />
        </ListItem>
    );
};

export default SidebarItem;
```

And this is my test so far:

```
import React from 'react';

import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { render, screen, RenderResult } from '@testing-library/react';
import SidebarItem from '../SidebarItem';

describe('SidebarItem', () => {
    // afterEach(() => {
    //     jest.clearAllMocks();
    // });

    // afterAll(() => {
    //     jest.restoreAllMocks();
    // });

    let documentBody: RenderResult;

    beforeEach(()=> {
        documentBody = render(<SidebarItem/>) // I get an error here
    })

});
```

I get a TS error:
`'SidebarItem' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof SidebarItem'?ts(2749)`

My initial guess was that I was using out-of-date versions for either Jest, RTL, or Typescript. I've already updated both RTL, Jest, and Typescript. I've also set up my jest.config.js to the `jsdom` test environment. I'm also following most RTL tutorials on the web and haven't seen anyone get a similar error than the one I'm seeing.

Answer (score 20):

I had this exact same issue and could not find anything about it.

I finally discovered that it was due to my test file being named spec.ts instead of spec.tsx.

Tests that uses jsx need to be in a tsx file due to the typescript definition of a generic being <>.

Answer (score 4):

Me too, I got the error

you can change the file name :

```
  SidebarItem.test.ts to SidebarItem.test.tsx
```